# How can i add or remove nodes to a layout while program is runnin in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, layout, task

I'm writing a code in javafx that, based on a string, build a layout and after i press a specific button it will read another string and build a complete different layout. this is the code:

```
Service<Void> cicle = new Service<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                String[] map = { "10", "10", "logo" };

                boolean waiting = false;

                Timer.start();
                while (Timer.update() / 1000 < time) {
                    if (!waiting) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i += 3) {
                            Label gigi = new Label("hi");
                            gigi.setLayoutX(Integer.parseInt(map[i]));
                            gigi.setLayoutX(Integer.parseInt(map[i + 1]));
                            // HERE is where i shoul add the label gigi
                        }
                        waiting = true;
                    }
                    System.out.println(Timer.update());
                }
                end();
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

but if i use layout.getChildrens().add(node) it doesn't work and if i rebuild entirely the scene for the stage it stops the program

Comment: and i can't translate the label because now i've added it for debugging purpose but in the future it will read what to add in the _string[] map_

Comment: You shouldn't update the GUI from a background thread. Use `Platform.runLater` to do the GUI update (in this case adding the `Label`s). BTW: what is the purpose of delaying the `end()` call and why don't you rewrite the loop as `if(Timer.update() / 1000 < time) {for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i += 3) { Label gigi = new Label("hi"); gigi.setLayoutX(Integer.parseInt(map[i]));
gigi.setLayoutX(Integer.parseInt(map[i + 1])); /* HERE is where i shoul add the label gigi*/ System.out.println(Timer.update()); while (Timer.update() / 1000 < time){System.out.println(Timer.update());} } }`

Comment: @fabian i delay the call of end() because i’ve to add a label every time i press a button in a specific limit of time (Timer.update < time) so if i’m waiting nothing appen but when i press the button waiting becomes false and i add the label. if the time run out the program tell it to the user with the end()

Comment: @fabian you where right; i'v made up this `for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i += 3) {
        Label gigi = new Label("Ciao");
        gigi.setLayoutX(Integer.parseInt(map[i]));
        gigi.setLayoutX(Integer.parseInt(map[i + 1]));
        Platform.runLater(() -> layout.getChildren().add(gigi));
       }`
and inside the task it works perfectly (outside it didn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used Platform.runLater and it works